# Bamboo and NuGet or how to manage different versions of your project

Tags: c#, nuget, bamboo

We've got a product that consists around 20+ projects. The problem is, that we've introduced breaking changes earlier this year and now need to always compile the product in version 8 as well as version 9. (At least for now, since we're going to kill version 8 eventually.)

Currently each of us has an identical folder structure with several solutions, that each only contain the projects neccessary to debug a certain module of the product. The projects reference themselfs by relative paths and -ofcourse- Bamboo is not liking it. So I wanted to go for NuGet. [Correct me if thats already wrong]

Now each project, that has been affected by the breaking changes, has a second set of build configs (Debug_V9 and Release_V9), which each add a symbol "V9", which triggers the breaking changes. (Yuck)

Now I'm currently trying to figure out how I can manage both Versions - and compile them using Bamboo - while using NuGet as a source. Ideally, I want to compile every project with V8/V9 configuration, create a NuGet package of each version and push it to our private server for the next builds. [BTW: Is this usually done in one package? Like with framework versions?]

Currently, I'm using two Tasks in Bamboo: one msbuild with /property:Configuration=Release_V8 and another with Release_V9 and different output-paths and it seems to work just fine: I'm able to aquire two sets of artifacts, I'm able to pack two nuget-Packages and push them.

However, I'm not sure how to set up the plan for the next project, since this was the first one, which does not have any dependencies. Specifically the problem will be getting different NuGet packages for V8/V9.

What's a good way to achive this? Second set of solutions with different packages? Branching? Not using NuGet? How to tell Bamboo where to find relatively referenced projects then? Always checking out every repository?